# iphone 3g jailbroken ios5 using whitedoor

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store, jailbreak

I have jailbroken my iphone 3g to ios5 using whitedoor tutorial, after this i faced two problem:

1. The version in setting>about is displayed as 3.1.1 but it has all ios5 features like icloud, UI etc so would like to know is there any prob in this?
2. and I am not able to install any apps from istore or cydia so please help me is suggesting
   what can be done now? acctually i want to download and use talk a tone application but not able to do so.

Comment: You should try [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whited00r include iOS5 features in a modified iOS3, so it isn't a real iOS5 and you can't install iOS5 apps

Comment: thanks for the answer,but i dont want to install ios5 app , i just simply wants to install app which support me device please let me know   how i can install app which support ios 3?

Comment: with Withed00r, if you enter in the app store icon, you´ll find 3 icons inside, one for the real app store, other for a special store with iOS 3 compatible apps, and the last one for cydia.

Comment: but even the cydia appliations are not getting install as it says that ios 4.3 is required

Comment: It depends on the app, if the developer doesn't suppor iOS 3 anymore there is nothing you can do. Use the 3 store, all the apps there support iOS 3